# My bootstrap buttons lose properties and wiggle on hover state in Angular JS, strange?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm developing an application in AngularJS, making use of Angular-UI and the Bootstrap directives for Angular as well. So far so good, except the other day I started noticing that the buttons in one portion of my app wiggle and lose margin when I hover over them. If you notice in the linked video, the "+" button in the top right also wiggles when other buttons are hovered over. These aren't the only elements that seem to be doing this on the page, but they are the most obvious.

[MP4 screencast showing the symptoms.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jl4c883f061brs/ButtonsWiggle.mp4)

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: More info -- I'm using/following the code tips provided by JSHint when compiling the app. It recommends strict mode for a lot of things, but I don't know if that could cause this.

Comment: We will need to see code, also possibly make a jsfiddle showing the problem.

Comment: I just realized how difficult it's going to be to make a fiddle of this. Give me a little while haha.

Comment: You may have an easier time with plunker

Comment: Nah the strict mode won't cause this, dont worry

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with how bootstrap renders the tooltips. Wrapping it in a `div` fixes the problem.